# Craft 3 Author Photo

Tags: craft3

Trying to display the author photo of the entry (it's there for sure).  The Craft 2 way I used **entry.author.photoUrl** but that is not working so I tried **entry.author.photo.url** and that does not show anything and no error or warnings.

Is what I am doing correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{{ entry.getAuthor().getPhoto().getUrl() }}
```

Here is the [function](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master/src/elements/User.php#L1180). Of course if the author has no photo you'll receive nothing (but an exception). Furthermore this function returns the URL not a HTML tag.

Comment: Thanks Robin! I tried that and still get nothing, even though the profile pic of the author is present. hmmmm

Comment: What does `entry.getAuthor.photoId` or `entry.getAuthor().getPhoto().id` output?

Comment: That returns 279

Comment: Seems like an invalid configuration. You can dump the volume in order to see the url setting. `{{ dump(entry.getAuthor().getPhoto().getVolume()) }}` there must be an attribute `url`/ `hasUrls` if it's empty you have to change the settings in the corresponding volume in your cp

Comment: Thanks again Robin :) . That was it, the config in assets had @storage/userPhotos. Once I changed File System Path to @webroot/images/blogs/userPhotos and made it accessible to public, it worked!